# Vim doesn't respect inoremap bind in insert mode for windows wsl config

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, microsoft-windows

I have these two configs

```
:nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%F %r")<CR>P

:inoremap <F5> <C-R>=strftime("%F %r")<CR>
```

In normal mode f5 inserts date-time, but in insert mode it doesn't insert anything.

I am using windows WSL on alacritty.

[1] Reference https://superuser.com/questions/451340/how-to-insert-the-date-into-vim

Comment: works for me with current master vim and most recent alacritty.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/x1P4Hcy.gif